# Build error while deploying Google Cloud Java Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a cloud function with Java-11 runtime and the build is failing.
Here is the stack trace:

```
ERROR: build step 5 "us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200820_12_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 2
ERROR
Finished Step #5 - "exporter"
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding cache layer 'google.java.functions-framework:functions-framework'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding cache layer 'google.java.gradle:cache'
Step #5 - "exporter": *** Images (sha256:d1b6b49691d3674ea9676b7f6933d6d2dfdac6151e6cc72e29a6159e7d7f5394):
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding label 'google.builder-version'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding label 'google.source-archive'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding layer 'config'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding layer 'launcher'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding 1/1 app layer(s)
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding layer 'google.java.functions-framework:functions-framework'
Step #5 - "exporter": Adding layer 'google.utils.archive-source:src'
Step #5 - "exporter": Already have image (with digest): us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200820_12_RC00
Starting Step #5 - "exporter"
Step #4 - "builder": Already have image (with digest): us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200820_12_RC00
***Build steps here, not pasting because my code is here***
Starting Step #4 - "builder"
Finished Step #3 - "restorer"
Step #3 - "restorer": Already have image (with digest): us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200820_12_RC00
Starting Step #3 - "restorer"
Finished Step #2 - "analyzer"
Step #2 - "analyzer": Already have image (with digest): us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200820_12_RC00
Starting Step #2 - "analyzer"
Finished Step #1 - "detector"
Step #1 - "detector": google.utils.label              0.0.1
Step #1 - "detector": google.java.functions-framework 0.9.0
Step #1 - "detector": google.java.gradle              0.9.0
Step #1 - "detector": google.utils.archive-source     0.0.1
Step #1 - "detector": us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200820_12_RC00
Step #1 - "detector": Status: Downloaded newer image for us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200820_12_RC00
Step #1 - "detector": Digest: sha256:335c80ce3fd84e8f1d5152b60951274173f79f460d4995bac26ecb0cf0964007
```

I am trying to deploy it using the command line tool as so:

```
gcloud functions deploy testFunction --entry-point functions.TestFunction --runtime java11 --trigger-http --memory 256MB --allow-unauthenticated
```

I don't have an idea of what the error means and what to do to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to run the function locally?

Comment: In addition to Guillaume's question, was it working for you before? If yes, did you make any changes to the build config?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you include enough information so that anyone can reproduce this error, including the code, how you build it, and how you deploy it.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes the function runs locally.

Comment: @DenisT. no this is my first time deploying it.

Comment: Could you please update your question adding a minimum reproducible **code** along with the relevant **pom.xml**?

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently this happens when the function deployment is timing out. I don't know why that was happening but I just redeployed it over and over again until it went through.